# Edit and Delete specific User in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

As the title says. I'am trying to enable a delete and edit system for the administrator.

The administrator specifies a datetime and userid which matches the data in the database and display that choice given.

Now I need to know how to edit or delete that specific data.

Model:

```
public partial class Stamping
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string StampingType { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Aviato.Models.Stamping>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Timestamp)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StampingType) @foreach (var item in Model) {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Timestamp)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StampingType)

        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item.UserId  }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  id=item.UserId  })}
```

Controller:

```
    [AuthenticateRoles(Roles = "admin")]
public class StampingsController : Controller
{
    private AviatoModel db = new AviatoModel(); //Database Connection.

    public ActionResult Index(Stamping model)
    {
        var startTime = model.Timestamp;
        var endTime = model.Timestamp.AddDays(1);

        var stampings = db.Stampings.Where(s => s.Timestamp >= startTime && s.Timestamp <= endTime)
            .Where(s => s.UserId == model.UserId).ToList();

        return View(stampings);
    }

        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        var stamping = db.Stampings.Find(id); /*An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.*/

        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "SocialSecurityNumber", stamping.UserId);
        return View(stamping);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "UserId,Timestamp,StampingType")] Stamping stamping)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(stamping).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "SocialSecurityNumber", stamping.UserId);
        return View(stamping);
    }

        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Stamping stamping = db.Stampings.Find(id); //Same error as in Edit ActionResult.
        if (stamping == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(stamping);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Stamping stamping = db.Stampings.Find(id);
        db.Stampings.Remove(stamping);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

How shall I solve this? Iv'e tried Googling around the Error, with no success though.

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the error you are having?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.

Comment: Yes exactly, on both...

Comment: Make sure to include the *relevant* exception message and stack-trace (or other "not working" indicator) in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity has a composite primary key consisting of both `UserId` and `Timestamp` but you are only passing a single value into the `Find()` method. That method requires a value for each column specified in the primary key.

You should either fix the key to only be on a single column (remove the `Key` attribute from `Timestamp`) or pass in both values:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, DateTime timestamp)
{
    var stamping = db.Stampings.Find(id, timestamp);
    //snip
}
```

And don't forget to change the view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item.UserId, timestamp = item.Timestamp })
```

Comment: I implemented it and got:

System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'timeStamp' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.DateTime)' in 'Aviato.Controllers.StampingsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: So the question now is how to save the data, the UserId and StampingType is null when I breakpointed the HttpPost ActionResult...